# Find the names of recipes where at least 3 oz. (quantity) of every ingredient are used

Tags: sql

```
INGREDIENT(ingredient-id,name,price-ounce)
RECIPE(recipe-id,name,country,time)
USES(rid,iid,quantity)
```

rid is a foreign key to recipe-id and iid is a foreign key ingredient_id

Find the names of recipes where at least 3 oz. (quantity) of every ingredient are used. NOTE: this
means that, however many ingredients are used in a recipe, at least 3 oz. of each ingredient is used.

I've tried this code, but not sure if its correct.

```
SELECT  name
FROM    recipe
WHERE   recipe_ID IN(SELECT rid
            FROM    USES
            WHERE   quantity>=3);
```

I don't get an error but not sure if its getting the correct results.

Would this code get the correct result:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCCIb.png)

### EDIT

The code from the image...

```
SELECT name
FROM   recipe
WHERE  recipe_id IN (SELECT rid
                     FROM   uses
                     WHERE  rid NOT IN (SELECT rid
                                        FROM   uses
                                        WHERE  quantity < 3))
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery will match *any* "Uses" row that has quantity >= 3. So, you will end with the list of recipes that has *at least one* ingredient with quantity >= 3.

What you want is that *none* of Uses should be less than 3 in order to match a recipe.

I would do some "double negative" here (NOT IN, and use "<" instead of ">=") :

```sql
SELECT  name
FROM    recipe
WHERE   recipe_ID NOT IN(SELECT rid
            FROM    USES
            WHERE   quantity<3);
```

With this you will get every recipe that *doesn't have* any ingredients with quantity *less* than 3, which is equivalent to having all ingredients with quantity greater than 3.