# How would I find the ingredients that belong to only one recipe?

Tags: sql

```
INGREDIENT(ingredient-id,name,price-ounce)
RECIPE(recipe-id,name,country,time)
USES(rid,iid,quantity)
```

rid is a foreign key to recipe-id and iid is a foreign key ingredient_id

How would I find the ingredients that belong to only one recipe?

I've tried a few ways but am unsure how to approach this.

Comment: [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58170169/find-the-names-of-recipes-where-at-least-3-oz-quantity-of-every-ingredient-ar) recipe question? ;-)

Comment: I might ask one more recipe question to see if it can be done in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the ingedients that appear in exactly one recipe (`HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`):

```
SELECT ingredient_id,
       name
FROM   (SELECT   ingredient.ingredient_id,
                 ingredient.name,
                 COUNT(*)
        FROM     ingredient
        JOIN     uses
          ON     ingredient.ingredient_id = uses.iid
        GROUP BY ingredient.ingredient_id,
                 ingredient.name
        HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
       )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just use aggregation:

```
select u.iid
from uses u
group by u.iid
having count(distinct u.rid) = 1;
```

If you want the name (instead of the id), then you can join to the ingredients table.

Note:  the `count(distinct)` allows an ingredient to be used multiple times for the same recipe.  If that is not allowed, then use `count(*)` instead.